# Enable stripe button upon bootstrap validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to use BootstrapValidator to validate couple of fields and enable stripe button upon validation. The problem is that the button is enabled once any of the fields are validated. I am trying to enabled the stripe button once both fields are validated.(ignore the datepicker field). below is my javascript code.

```
$('#myform')
    .bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        //live: 'submitted',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            fname: {
                message: 'The first name is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The first name must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    /*remote: {
                        url: 'remote.php',
                        message: 'The username is not available'
                    },*/
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        message: 'The first name can only consist of alphabetical letters'
                    }
                }
            },
            lname: {
                message: 'The last name is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The last name must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    /*remote: {
                        url: 'remote.php',
                        message: 'The username is not available'
                    },*/
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        message: 'The last name can only consist of alphabetical letters'
                    }
                }
            },

        }
    })
    .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
        // Prevent submit form
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form     = $(e.target),
            validator = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
        $form.find('#result').html('Thanks for signing up. Now you can sign in as ' + validator.getFieldElements('fname').val()).show();
    });


    $('.stripe-button-el').attr("disabled", true );
});
```

And this is the form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Full name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First name" id="fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" id="lname"  />
        </div>

    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Pick a Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="date" type="text" id="datepicker"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
                <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
                data-amount="5000" data-zip-code = "true" data-description="Whatever">
                </script>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" id='results'></label>

    </div>



</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an event triggered with every keystroke to determine whether the form is valid. Once you know its valid, you can take action on the button. [BootstrapValidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com)'s API includes everything you need to do this (other than capturing the event itself).

You can append this [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to your `$('#myform')` chain:

```
.on('keyup', function() {
    // Get your form's validator
    var validator = $('#myform').data('bootstrapValidator');

    // Validate the form
    validator.validate();

    // Check if the form is valid
    if (validator.isValid()) {
        // Perform action on Stripe button
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it and now I get an error as `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'validator.validate')`. Also, do I have to chain this after `.on('success.form.fv', function(e)...` or just by itself after `$('#myform)`. Thanks!

Comment: @arashaga You don't need to chain it. You can add the snippet I provided above directly after a new `$('#myform')`.

Comment: thank you it works now. But the button flashes on each keyup. I was wondering if there was a more graceful way to enable the button.

Comment: @arashaga You can use a variable in a closure or a global variable to maintain state (to "remember") if the button was previously enabled. Or more simply, you can add another statement inside the conditional (next to `isValid`) to check whether the button is *not* yet enabled.